# JNA return array of struct as parameter

Tags: java, arrays, struct, jna

I have a C function, which creates an array of structs

```c
int createArray(myStruct** data_array);
```

From C I call the function like this:

```c
myStruct* data_array;
int size = createArray(&data_array);
```

I want to call `createArray` in a similar way with JNA. I've generated the wrapper using JNAerator.

```java
int createArray(myStruct.ByReference[] data_array);
```

I don't know what to pass to the JNA method `createArray` since `data_array` is actually a output parameter. I actually think the generated JNA method is wrong since I don't want to pass an array of `myStruct`, I want to receive one.

Shouldn't the parameter of the JNA method be `PointerByReference`?

Here are some tries that didn't worked for me

```
PointerByReference ptr = new PointerByReference();
int size = api.createArray(ptr); //Invalid memory access
```

```
myStruct.ByReference[] array = new myStruct.ByReference[10];
Arrays.fill(stLinks, new myStruct.ByReference()); //without this I get NullpointerException
int size = api.createArray(array); //Invalid memory access
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the problem with Invalid memory access was caused by other side effects. I had to call other functions from the API before I can use createArray.

The working code is now:

```
PointerByReference ptr = new PointerByReference();
            
int size = api.createArray(ptr);
            
Pointer ptrToFirst = ptr.getValue();
myStruct firstElement = new myStruct(ptrToFirst);
myStruct[] array = (myStruct []) firstElement.toArray(size);

//Work with Array

api.deleteArray();
```

Comment: So it looks like my first answer was closer.  And accurate if you swap Pointer to PointerByReference.... glad you solved it.

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't the parameter of the JNA method be `PointerByReference`?

Debugging this requires figuring out what exactly the native method does, which is likely documented in the API and not obvious from the method signatures.

`PointerByReference` allocates a pointer-sized block of memory on the Java side, and is generally the correct thing to pass when native is filling it with a value.  After your clarification/answer it appears your invalid memory access was external to this code.

Your attempt to allocate an array of structures doesn't work because they require contiguous memory, which you need to allocate using `toArray()` if you're responsible for the allocation -- but it looks like you're not!

So you can pass a `PointerByReference` and extract its pointed-to (`Pointer`) value using `getValue()`.  You could then use that pointer in a `Structure` constructor to populate the Java-side structure (array).

```java
PointerByReference pbr = new PointerByReference();
int size = api.createArray(pbr);
MyStruct[] foo = (MyStruct[]) new MyStruct(pbr.getValue()).toArray(size);
// you may need to `read()` indices past 0 from this array
```

Comment: Well thanks. The native code allocates the memory. There is also a deleteArray function. If I pass PointerByReference I get an Error Invalid memory access. If I pass myArray.ByReference[] filled with 10 default elements, I get the same error.

Comment: Are you sure native allocates?  Try passing new mystruct(),toArray(size).  And try passing an array of Pointers.

Comment: yes I'm totally sure. You can see the valid call from C in the question. The pointer isn't preallocated with an array or something like that. But nevertheless passing your argument (Structure[]) causes Invalid memory access too.

Comment: @yannick818 Updated my answer.  Sorry I didn't look carefully enough at the working C code the first time!